# Dynamically changing properties of Label text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have text with "wild characters", like "@ARed text" where @A is sign for red colour. I need to replace @A with some function (or something like that) so wherever there is @A in text, text font becomes red coloured. I have several colours (@B, @C...) so for every of them I need to do same thing, just different colour.

So, "@ASome red text @BSome green text" would be coloured red and green respectively (can't find text colouring here on SO).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: you can create a control, over the Label and capture the Render. On the Render you can change your text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is capture the `PreRender` event of the label and test for `YourLabel.Text.Substring(0, 1)` and if that is the at-sign (@) then conditionally test (I'd use a switch) the second character.  You can then get the rest of the string without the `@A` and set the Label's text then, and format according to the property characters.

Something like this:

```
protected void YourLabel_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LabelText = YourLabel.Text;
    bool NewForeColor = false;

    if (LabelText.Left(0, 1) == "@")
    {
        switch(LabelText.Substring(1, 1))
        {
            case "A":
                YourLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
                NewForeColor = true;
                break;
            case "B":
                // you get the idea
                break;
        }
        if (NewForeColor)
            YourLabel.Text = LabelText.Substring(2, LabelText.Length - 2);
    }
}
```

*Edit: this is untested code, but you should get the general idea of the logic.*